# Tkinter Python, How to create a Y-xis Scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter window with lots of images. However I cannot create a scrollbar going along the y-axis. I have tried multiple times, however I get too confused. Does tkinter have a widget for a scrollbar? I have noted out the image labels, as you will not have these images. Please do not be alarmed by the massive amount of code. Most of it Is just defining labels.
Here is my imports.

```
Don't know why it seems that every time I copy past the code it doesn't indent properly.
```

The stack overflow code indent system is not letting me indent this code properly. So here's a pastebin link: 
https://pastebin.com/Um8zv3Qr

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font
import mysql.connector
import random
import smtplib
import config
import string
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
root=tk.Tk()
PatrolOverview=tk.Frame(root)
PatrolOverview.grid(row=0,column = 0, sticky= 'news')
SmallTextFont=Font(family="Arial",size="14")



#Badger Tkinter Variables
BadgerPL=tk.StringVar()
BadgerAPL=tk.StringVar()
BadgerScore=tk.IntVar()
    #Beaver Tkinter Variables
BeaverPL=tk.StringVar()
BeaverAPL=tk.StringVar()
BeaverScore=tk.IntVar()
    #Buffalo Tkinter Variables
BuffaloPL=tk.StringVar()
BuffaloAPL=tk.StringVar()
BuffaloScore=tk.IntVar()
    #Bull Tkinter Variables
BullPL=tk.StringVar()
BullAPL=tk.StringVar()
BullScore=tk.IntVar()
    #Bulldog Tkinter Variables
BulldogPL=tk.StringVar()
BulldogAPL=tk.StringVar()
BulldogScore=tk.IntVar()
    #Cobra Tkinter Variables
CobraPL=tk.StringVar()
CobraAPL=tk.StringVar()
CobraScore=tk.IntVar()





def PatrolOverviewRaiseFrame():
    AnimalNameList=["Badger","Beaver","Buffalo","Bull","Bulldog","Cobra"]
    for row in AnimalNameList:
        print(row)
        if row==("Badger"):
            #BadgerImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=BadgerImage)
            #BadgerImageLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)
            BadgerNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Badger",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
            BadgerNameLabel.grid(row=3,column=2)
            BadgerPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BadgerPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
            BadgerPLLabel.grid(row=3, column=3)
            BadgerAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BadgerAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
            BadgerAPLLabel.grid(row=3, column=4)
            BadgerScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BadgerScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
            BadgerScoreBox.grid(row=3,column=5)
        if row==("Beaver"):
                #BeaverImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=BeaverImage)
                #BeaverImageLabel.grid(row=4, column=1)
                BeaverNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Beaver",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BeaverNameLabel.grid(row=4,column=2)
                BeaverPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BeaverPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BeaverPLLabel.grid(row=4, column=3)
                BeaverAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BeaverAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BeaverAPLLabel.grid(row=4, column=4)
                BeaverScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BeaverScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
                BeaverScoreBox.grid(row=4,column=5)
        if row==("Buffalo"):
                #BuffaloImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=BuffaloImage)
                #BuffaloImageLabel.grid(row=5, column=1)
                BuffaloNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Buffalo",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BuffaloNameLabel.grid(row=5,column=2)
                BuffaloPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BuffaloPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BuffaloPLLabel.grid(row=5, column=3)
                BuffaloAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BuffaloAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BuffaloAPLLabel.grid(row=5, column=4)
                BuffaloScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BuffaloScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
                BuffaloScoreBox.grid(row=5,column=5)
        if row==("Bull"):
                #BullImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=BullImage)
                #BullImageLabel.grid(row=6, column=1)
                BullNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Bull",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BullNameLabel.grid(row=6,column=2)
                BullPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BullPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BullPLLabel.grid(row=6, column=3)
                BullAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BullAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BullAPLLabel.grid(row=6, column=4)
                BullScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BullScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
                BullScoreBox.grid(row=6,column=5)
        if row==("Bulldog"):
                #BulldogImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=BulldogImage)
                #BulldogImageLabel.grid(row=7, column=1)
                BulldogNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Bulldog",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BulldogNameLabel.grid(row=7,column=2)
                BulldogPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BulldogPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BulldogPLLabel.grid(row=7, column=3)
                BulldogAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BulldogAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                BulldogAPLLabel.grid(row=7, column=4)
                BulldogScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=BulldogScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
                BulldogScoreBox.grid(row=7,column=5)
        if row==("Cobra"):
                #CobraImageLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, image=CobraImage)
                #CobraImageLabel.grid(row=8, column=1)
                CobraNameLabel=tk.Label(PatrolOverview,text="Cobra",font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                CobraNameLabel.grid(row=8,column=2)
                CobraPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=CobraPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                CobraPLLabel.grid(row=8, column=3)
                CobraAPLLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, textvariable=CobraAPL, font=SmallTextFont, bg="white")
                CobraAPLLabel.grid(row=8, column=4)
                CobraScoreBox= tk.Spinbox(PatrolOverview, textvariable=CobraScore,from_=0,to_=500,font=SmallTextFont,bg="white")
                CobraScoreBox.grid(row=8,column=5)

raise_frame(PatrolOverview)
UnleashAnimals=tk.Button(root,text="UnleashAnimals",command=PatrolOverviewRaiseFrame)
UnleashAnimals.grid(row=1,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Copying and pasting seems to have worked for me...

Comment: _"Does tkinter have a widget for a scrollbar?"_ can be answered by reading existing tkinter documentation.

Comment: Well, it doesn't so how to I make one?